# How to insert textbox value & dxDatagrid all selected value in database on one single button click?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, dx-data-grid

I am having input tag(textbox) and dxDatagrid. I am able to pass all selected value from dxDatagrid to database, but i also want to pass text box(which is outside of grid) value along with it on one button click.

```
$("#myButton").dxButton({
    text: "Test",
    onClick: function () {
        var stones = (JSON.stringify(dataGrid.getSelectedRowsData()));
        console.log(stones);
        updatedetgridReturnShip(stones);
    }
});



function updatedetgridReturnShip(stonedetailsarr){
    $('#sloader').show();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'php/insertGridReturnShipment.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            returnstonedetails: stonedetailsarr,
            txtRefnoval : txtRefnoval
        },
        success: function (result) {
            alert(result);
            $('#sloader').hide();
            $("#myImportModal").modal("hide");
        }
    });
}
```

PHP Server side code:

```
$StoneArr = json_decode($returnstonedetails, true);

$updstmt = '';

foreach ($StoneArr as $Stone){
  $textboxval = $_POST['textboxval'];

  $refVal = json_decode($textboxval, true);

  $updstmt .= 'CALL return_ship_stones('.'"'.$Stone["carat"].'"'.',
  '.'"'.$Stone["clarity"].'"'.','.'"'.$Stone["color"].'"'.','.'"'.$Stone["invcno"].'"'.','.'"'.$Stone["invoicedate"].'"'.', '.'"'.$Stone["lab"].'"'.', 
  '.'"'.$Stone["measurement"].'"'.' , '.'"'.$Stone["ppt"].'"'.' , '.'"'.$Stone["qstonesid"].'"'.' , '.'"'.$Stone["qty"].'"'.' ,
  '.'"'.$Stone["reportno"].'"'.' , '.'"'.$Stone["shape"].'"'.' , '.'"'.$Stone["totalvalue"].'"'.', '.'"'.$refVal["referenceid"].'"'.');';
}
```

on one single click how to pass both textbox, and dxDatagrid value in database

Comment: i am new to a PHP and JS, any help will be appreciated. I want to pass textbox and gridvalue combine in database.

Comment: Where is your html code for textbox, are you using any id for textbox

Comment: <tr> <td><label for="reference">Reference #:</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="refno" id="refno"></td>
</tr>

Comment: this is for grid. <div id="gridReturnShip">
                        </div>

Comment: when you are passing the textbox value it is not any array. so no need to do json_decode()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **jquery** method to get the value from the text input by id and pass it to **ajax** data parameter:

```
$('#refno').val().trim()
```

Code Below:

```
function updatedetgridReturnShip(stonedetailsarr){
    $('#sloader').show();

      $.ajax({
          url: 'php/insertGridReturnShipment.php',
          dataType: 'json',
          type: "POST",
          data: {
              returnstonedetails: stonedetailsarr,
              txtRefnoval : txtRefnoval,
              textboxval: $('#refno').val().trim()
          },
          success: function (result) {
              alert(result);
              $('#sloader').hide();
              $("#myImportModal").modal("hide");
          }
      });
  }
```

PHP code:

```
<?
$returnstonedetails = $_REQUEST['returnstonedetails'];

$StoneArr = json_decode($returnstonedetails, true);

$updstmt = '';

foreach ($StoneArr as $Stone){
  $textboxval = $_REQUEST['textboxval'];
  $refVal = $textboxval;

  $updstmt .= 'CALL return_ship_stones('.'"'.$Stone["carat"].'"'.',
  '.'"'.$Stone["clarity"].'"'.','.'"'.$Stone["color"].'"'.','.'"'.$Stone["invcno"].'"'.','.'"'.$Stone["invoicedate"].'"'.', '.'"'.$Stone["lab"].'"'.', 
  '.'"'.$Stone["measurement"].'"'.' , '.'"'.$Stone["ppt"].'"'.' , '.'"'.$Stone["qstonesid"].'"'.' , '.'"'.$Stone["qty"].'"'.' ,
  '.'"'.$Stone["reportno"].'"'.' , '.'"'.$Stone["shape"].'"'.' , '.'"'.$Stone["totalvalue"].'"'.', '.'"'.$refVal.'"'.');';
}
```

Comment: hi @Rishab,thanks for quick reply, how can i pass to PHP server side combine in foreach loop.

Comment: Can you add your server side code will help you out

Comment: Hi @rishab, i shared please check,  i want to pass that #refno with each n every row of grid.

Comment: Hi @Rishab, Thank you,  for your support.

Comment: Hi @Rishab, one problem here, if you can help,                                                                                      getting this error while inserting using stored procedure,                                                                        Error<br>Incorrect date value: '' for column ``.``.`_invoicedate` at row 1<br>1292

Comment: Hi what is database structure type for that column?

Comment: it is "DATE" for table and "DATETIME"in procedure @Rishab

Comment: if data type is DATE then you can't add DATETIME value in it .. try to add date only

Comment: hi @Rishab, i am passing only date but not working.

Comment: I am getting error at database level, and i am passing date only not datetime